# Print and use array element in C

Tags: c, arrays, element

So what I'm trying to do is input an array and then using its elements. For eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main()
{
int s[100],i;

for(i=0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
{scanf("%d",&s[i]);}

printf("s[1] = %d",s[1];

}
```

If I input 12345, I want it to return s[1], which would be 2. I know how to print the whole array, but I just want one or more elements, and it seems I can't figure this seemingly easy problem.

Comment: How do you decide which elements you want? What is the question?

Comment: BTW: Automatic (stack) variables in C are indeterminate. You really don't want to use them before you initialised them manually.

Comment: You can use `strlen()` on null-terminated strings; your array is not an array of characters, and its contents will be indeterminate. It would help if you posted compilable code; you're missing a `)` on your `printf()` statement.  You should include a newline at the end of the format string, too.

Comment: Always test the return value of `scanf()` and take appropriate action, or your program might easily choke on unexpected input.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Please try to give more detail of what you want your end result to be.

Comment: The input `12345` is a perfectly valid int value, and will be assigned to `s[0]` the first time 'round. `s[1]`, will be untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
```

Using an uninitialised (indeterminate) variable can have surprising results. Anyway, you want the element count here: `sizeof s/sizeof *s`.

```
{scanf("%d",&s[i]);}
```

Always test how many elements were assigned in `scanf`. That is your second condition for abort btw.
Also, if you only want to convert one digit, use a field length: `"%1d"`

> If I input 12345, I want it to return s[1], which would be 2. I know how to print the whole array, but I just want one or more elements, and it seems I can't figure this seemingly easy problem.

That looks like you wanted to read a **string of digits**, and not **numbers**. Use this:

```
char digits[100];
if(scanf("%99[0-9]", digits) != 1)
    abort();
```

Above can read a string of up to 99 digits, aborting if no digits found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
char s[100],i;
scanf("%s",s);
for(i=0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
{
     printf("s[%d] = %c", i, s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one input string, then you could try this:

```
char s[100];

fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
```

and output its contents like this:

```
for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", s[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is what you want:

- Read the user input character-by-character by using `fgets()`.
- Check the input. If it is a new line character (user pressed enter), then you are done looping.
- Otherwise, store the character in the array and keep looping.
- Add a null termination character `\0` at the end of the string.
- Print the string.

Hint: when the number of iterations aren't known in advance, such as in this case, a `while` or `do-while` loop should be used. `for` loops should only be used when the number of iterations are known.